# Как открыть активити другого приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Написал приложение, которое генерирует файл и картинку. Можно ли в данном приложении сделать так, чтоб пользователь нажал кнопку и открылось активити в другом приложении, например окно создания сообщения в Outlook (или в другой почте) и эти файлы вложились в тело письма?

Comment: Да, надо отправить соответствующий интент.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не подскажите, как узнать, какой интент отвечает за открытие определенного активити в другом приложении?

Comment: Иногда это можно узнать в документации к этому приложения. Но чаще отправляется интент некоторого обобщённого типа с указанием типа данных и система предлагает пользователю самому выбрать, в каком приложении эти данные открыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправить письмо с аттачем можно следующим образом:

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
mailIntent.setType("application/image");
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "foo@bar.com"); 
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Mail subject"); 
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mail text"); 
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Image.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send e-mail"));
```

В общем случае нужно создать `intent` с определенным действием и, собственно, вызвать `startActivity(intent)`.

Советую почитать подробнее про [`implicit intents`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html).